# Servlet not receiving call from $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I want to send some data from a JSP to Java in order to execute a query from Java. I'm running the server through *Tomcat*.

I've added the **servlet** to web.xml like this:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CreateInstallationServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>webapp.CreateInstallationServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CreateInstallationServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CreateInstallationServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I'm calling a **javascript function** from this jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create New Entry</h1>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="create()">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
        City: <input type="text" name="city" required><br>
        Country: <input type="text" name="country" required><br>
        <button type="submit">Create Installation</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"><%@include file="/WEB-INF/javascript/create.js" %></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript file looks like this:

```
const create = () => {
    const name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
    const city = document.querySelector('input[name="city"]').value;
    const country = document.querySelector('input[name="country"]').value;

    const formData = {
        name: name,
        city: city,
        country: country
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'CreateInstallationServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Form data sent successfully.');
            window.location.href = 'visualize.jsp';
        }
    });
}
```

The CreateInstallationServlet code looks like this:

```
package webapp;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/CreateInstallationServlet")
public class CreateInstallationServlet extends HttpServlet  {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse r) {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");

        System.out.println("called servlet");

        Utils utils = new Utils();
        try {
            utils.createInstallation(name, city, country);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `System.out.println()` is never executed.

Comment: Press F12 in your webbrowser to open the developer tools and analyze the 'Network' section. Do you see the XHR request there? If not then problem is in JS. If so then you need to check which response it has retrieved. 404? 500? Both speak for themselves.

Comment: The xhr request is there. On the first request it gives a 500. On every following, it gives a 404.

Comment: Answer of 500 is in server logs. Look there.